# Retrieve the value from three selects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I'm new on AngularJS, and I've been integrating a php application with angular.
Recently i am trying to get the values from three selects.

I made two files on the plunker editor as example
http://plnkr.co/edit/CA2D5RDvZeBQLnMUXFOH?p=preview

The selects are as follow:

`<body ng-app="MyForm">`

```
<!-- comment -->
        <div ng-controller="programsController">
        <select name="program" id="program" ng-model="program"
        ng-options="prog.name for prog in programs">
        </select>
        program.name {{program.name}}
        selected_program {{selected_program}}
        </div>

<!-- comment -->
        <div ng-controller="periodsController">
        <select name="period" id="period" ng-model="period"
        ng-options="period.name for period in periods">
        </select>
        </div>

<!-- comment -->
        <div ng-controller="teacherController">
        <select name="teacher" id="teacher" ng-model="teacher"
        ng-options="teacher.name for teacher in teachers">
        </select>
        </div>

        <button ng-click="vals()">Click</button>

    </div>
```

MyForm is the main module of the application

```
angular.module('MyForm',['Programs','Periods','Teachers'])
.factory('myFactory', function() {
    console.log('Factory loaded');
    var course = {
        program : 'no set',
        setValues : function (program){
            course.program=program;
            //course.period=period;
            //course.teacher=teacher;
        },
        sayHello : function(){
            alert('hello');
        }
    }
    //console.log(course);
    return course;
})

.controller('mainController',['$scope','myFactory',function($scope,myFactory){

    $scope.vals = function(){
        //myFactory.setValues(myFactory.program);
//myFactory.sayHello();

        alert('The values are:' +
            '\nProgram: ' + myFactory.program +
            '\nProgram: ' + myFactory.period +
            '\nProgram: ' + myFactory.teacher);
    }
}]) ;
```

Modules that fill the selects

```
angular.module('Programs',[])
    .factory('proFactory',function(){
        var selected_program = '0';
        console.log('From proFactory');
    })

    .controller('programsController',function($scope,myFactory){
        $scope.programs=[
        {ID:1 , name:'HTML'},
        {ID:2 , name: 'AngularJS'}
        ];

        $scope.program = $scope.programs[0];
        //myFactory.setValues($scope.program.ID);
});

angular.module('Periods',[])
    .controller('periodsController',function($scope){
    $scope.periods=[
        {ID:1 , name:'Jan-Feb'},
        {ID:2 , name: 'Mar-Apr'}
        ];
    $scope.period = $scope.periods[0];
});

angular.module('Teachers',[])
    .controller('teacherController',function($scope){
    $scope.teachers=[
        {ID:1 , name:'Mark Smith'},
        {ID:2 , name: 'Joe Cliff'}
        ];
    $scope.teacher = $scope.teachers[0];
});
```

I have tried to get the values of the three selects in order to send the data to another script and show them in an alert before, but i couldnt get that.

I have read that to share data between controllers is necesary to create a provider, and in this case i used a factory.

The factory has an object with three variables, program, period and teacher (the last two are commented), and two function, `setValues` to assign data and ´sayHello´ to test the factory.

I commented a code line that uses a function `sayHello` from the factory, so the factory is accesible.

The button in the html has the `ng-click=vals()` and that function is in the $scope of the mainController, when i click the button i pretend to assign the values of the selects and show them.

I have tried to assign the values through `myFactory.setValues(myFactory.program);` and in this way too `myFactory.setValues($scope.program);` but the `$scope.program` is in the scope of the `programsController`

Any comment or idea for this.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks benri.

I found another solution using the $parent.

In this case, the page has a `mainController` (from `myForm`module) that contains three  controllers from different modules.
The `$scope` for every controller is for each one. I mean that the $scope from the programsController can not be used in the periodsControllers.

The solution is:
Using the $parent.program in the ng-model from the `programsController`, this way angular says that the model is binded to the `$scope.program` from the `mainController`

The HTML is:

```
<div ng-controller="programsController">
        <select name="program" id="program" ng-model="$parent.program"
        ng-options="prog.name for prog in programs">
        </select>
</div>
```

and the Controller:

```
.controller('mainController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.vals = function(){
        alert('The values are:' +
            '\nProgram: ' + $scope.program.name);
    }
}]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need three controllers?
Three controllers is unnecessary hassle, you only need one controller to encompass all three selects

That way you can access all three values within the same scope and pass them to the factory. I'd recommend defining all your variables (periods, teachers, programs) in one scope too.

for ex

```
<body ng-app="MyForm">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <select name="program" id="program" ng-model="program"
         ng-options="prog.name for prog in programs">
        </select>
        program.name {{program.name}}
        selected_program {{selected_program}}


        <select name="period" id="period" ng-model="period"
         ng-options="period.name for period in periods">
        </select>

        <select name="teacher" id="teacher" ng-model="teacher"
         ng-options="teacher.name for teacher in teachers">
        </select>


    <button ng-click="vals()">Click</button>

    </div>
</body>
```

and in the js

```
angular.module('MyForm',['Programs'])
.factory('myFactory', function() {
    console.log('Factory loaded');
    var course = {
        program : 'no set',
        setValues : function (data){
            course.program=data.program;
            course.period=data.period;
            course.teacher=data.teacher;
        },
        sayHello : function(){
            alert('hello');
        }
    }
    //console.log(course);
    return course;
})

.controller('mainController',['$scope','myFactory', 'proFactory',function($scope,myFactory,proFactory){

    $scope.vals = function(){
        myFactory.setValues({
            program: $scope.program,
            period: $scope.period,
            teacher: $scope.teacher
        });

        alert('The values are:' +
            '\nProgram: ' + $scope.program +
            '\nProgram: ' + $scope.period +
            '\nProgram: ' + $scope.teacher);
    }

    // to store in programs factory:
    proFactory.set_program($scope.program);

}]) ;
```

EDIT:
If you really need to use a factory to pass data in between scopes, you'd define it like this:

```
angular.module('Programs',[])
.factory('proFactory',function(){
    var selected_program = '0';

    return {
        set_program: (function(program){ selected_program = program; }),
        get_program: (function(){ return selected_program; })
    };
});
```

The factory returns a set of methods to get/set your variables (the API)